# Direct2D use layers to update only a part of the drawing

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I have a Direct2D surface which needs real time updating in a part of it. So I'm creating the render target once and keep it:

```
D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES hp;
hp.hwnd = hh;
hp.pixelSize.width = rc.right;
hp.pixelSize.height = rc.bottom;
hp.presentOptions = D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_RETAIN_CONTENTS;

factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top)), &rT);
```

I'm drawing all the non-rt content

```
    rT->BeginDraw();
    ....
```

Then in a new layer, the RT content

```
    D2D1_LAYER_PARAMETERS lp = { x,
                NULL,
                D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE,
                D2D1::IdentityMatrix(),
                1.0,
                0,
                D2D1_LAYER_OPTIONS_NONE };

    rT->PushLayer(lp, 0);
    rT->DrawRectangle(...);
    rT->PopLayer();
```

and then

```
    rT->EndDraw();
```

When I want to draw real time, I only perform the latter set, i.e. after the PushLayer. However I'm not getting the old layer removed from the screen as I 'd wish.

Is there a way to update only a part of the Direct2D surface without rendering the whole thing?

Comment: You can render to texture and then on update only a part of that texture while copying the whole texture into backbuffer.

Comment: @VTT ok, do I do that in the old way (writing to a memory DC and save a HBITMAP), or there is another Direct2D way?

Comment: Modify the first member of [`D2D1_LAYER_PARAMETERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/ns-d2d1-d2d1_layer_parameters), The content bounds of the layer. Content outside these bounds is not guaranteed to render.